# spring jdbc.query() suggestion

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I need to execute the below query and get the list object.
Do you guys know how best to retrieve in `spring jdbc`?

Here is the SQL Query:

```
SELECT app_name, error_code, error_message FROM error_message
WHERE ( 
    (app_name = ? AND error_code = ?) OR 
    (app_name = ? AND error_code = ?) OR 
    (app_name = ? AND error_code = ?) OR 
    (app_name = ? AND error_code = ?) OR 
    (app_name = ? AND error_code = ?) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my sample code:

```
String sql = yoursql;

Object args[] = new Object[3];
args[0] = yourparam1;          
args[1] = yourparam2;          
args[2] = yourparam3;

getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, args, yourRowMapper);
```

You should add following code for rowmapper.

```
private RowMapper yourRowMapper= new YourRowMapperClass ();

public final class YourRowMapperClass implements RowMapper {
   public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

      YourResponse model = new YourResponse ();
      model.setresp1(rs.getDate(1));
      model.setresp2(rs.getDate(2));
      model.setresp3(rs.getString(3));

      return model;
    }
  }
```

Order is important for specifying the arguments. For example If we use searchType argument twice in our sql, we should define argument as below:

```
Object args[] = new Object[4];
args[0] = searchType;
args[1] = param1;
args[2] = searchType;
args[3] = param2;
```

If we customize the example for you,  you can use the following code:

```
Object args[] = new Object[10];
args[0] = appname;
args[1] = errorcode;
args[2] = appname;
args[3] = errorcode;
args[4] = appname;
args[5] = errorcode;
args[6] = appname;
args[7] = errorcode;
args[8] = appname;
args[9] = errorcode;
```

Comment: I changed my code and shared it as simple example. If you want specific examples, I can try to share new codes.

Comment: How to specify the arguments? Should I create map and pass it as argument? I need to specify the two arguments in the each predicate. app_name & error_code.

Comment: You do not need to create a map. Order is important for specifying. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have seen some examples where it says to use PreparedStatementCreator. Is there any advantages of using it? which one will be better or faster?

Comment: I'm sorry but I've never used it.

Comment: I have implemented the way you mentioned. I am not getting the list from the jdbctemplate.query. I also posted the query here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135306-jdbc-query-returning-null-LIST